# -moz-box does not work when child has % width

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, html, vertical-alignment

We're using the display:-moz-box/-webkit-box to vertically center a div within another div. If it works when the child div has an absolute width, it is not properly renderer on Firefox when the child's width is just a percentage.

```
<div style="background:yellow;height:40px;display:-moz-box;-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center">
    <div style="width:70%;background:blue;text-align:center">
        Hello World
    </div>
 </div>
```

Chrome
[image: Chrome OK]

Firefox
[image: Firefox KO]

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the issue :  http://jsfiddle.net/sBdWW/

Any help would be appreciated
Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an outdated flexbox specification.

- New [`flexbox` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) on MDN
- [W3C CSS Flexbox CR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)
- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmaier/sBdWW/1/), that seems to work in Firefox 23 and Chrome 28

Comment: Wow that was fast, and it Works like a charm ;) BTW What would be the equivalent for IE ?

Comment: Never tried IE and I don't have a Windows box around ATM to check, but http://caniuse.com/#search=flex says IE 10 is kinda supported with `-ms` prefix.

Comment: Perfect. Here's a fork of your fiddle for IE/Chrome/Firefox : http://jsfiddle.net/hberf/ . Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Your JSFiddle is not working in FF35, working well in Chrome40.